# Regex for phone number mismatch when boundary added

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a phone number with spaces, brackets and + sign in a phone number. I took the regex from ASP.Net Application and dis some modification. the below regex matches exactly but the problem is when I add a boundary to the regex the the matches vary, like match exclude the + sign and opening bracket.

Where did i do the wrong? what is the correct approach

```
string strRegex = @"((\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,5})";
string strTargetString = @"+91 9800013649 m +91 9900000000m" + "\n" + @"Tel:+91 (965) 25300300, Fax: (965) 25300017";
```

from the above string I want the below matches

Match

- +91 9800013649
- +91 (965) 25300300
- (965) 25300017

Mismatch

- +91 9900000000m

Comment: How come your matches this +91 9800013649 and not +91 9900000000? Both are having same pattern?

Comment: A boundary `\b` represents start or end of a `\w` after or before a non-word character `\W`. It won't include anything other than `\w`.

Comment: +91 9900000000 is followed by a character "M", I want to excluded those cases

Comment: @RAN_0915 what is the solution then?

Comment: For what purpose you are using boundary,rather than use negative looka head like `((\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,5})(?!\w)`

Comment: I want to extract all the phone number from the line but don't want those have extract character like 12 digit number or aPrefix or postfix character
if i add ^ and $ then I will not get individual numbers

Comment: @RAN_0915 this works if the phone number followed by a a character but what is its a 12 digit number of a prefix character to it

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/PqIkyj/2

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want phone number to not match that is followed by an alphabet, then try putting a negative lookahead and use this regex,

```
((\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,5}(?![a-z]+))
```

Check here and let me know if it works else I will further change the regex to suit your needs.

https://regex101.com/r/PqIkyj/1

Comment: negative list will be too high like Capital A-Z, another Digit, other language characters +91 9900000000É, +91 99000000009, +91 9900000000A, In these cases I can't add ach character here

Answer (score 0):

The first obligatory pattern is `\d{3}`, and it is a "word" char pattern, so you may put the word boundary `\b` or a negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` (to match only if not preceded with a digit) right before it. Then, you may add a word boundary or `(?!\d)` negative lookahead (to match only if not followed with a digit) after the last `\d{4,5}`:

```
(?:\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\b\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,5}\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5C%2B%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5Cs%29%3F%5C%28%3F%5Cb%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C%29%3F%5B%5Cs.-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B%5Cs.-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B4%2C5%7D%5Cb&i=%2B91%209800013649%20m%20%2B91%209900000000m%0D%0ATel%3A%2B91%20%28965%29%2025300300%2C%20Fax%3A%20%28965%29%2025300017).

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/m4J8aa):

```
string strRegex = @"(?:\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\b\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4,5}\b";
string strTargetString = @"+91 9800013649 m +91 9900000000m" + "\n" + @"Tel:+91 (965) 25300300, Fax: (965) 25300017";
string[] results = Regex.Matches(strTargetString, strRegex)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Output:

```
+91 9800013649
+91 (965) 25300300
(965) 25300017
```